# tsc is trying to resolve relative path modules in the wrong folder

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, node-modules

I'm using `npm link` to reference a typescript library I'm developing in my test project

Which means that my node_modules looks like this :

```
node_modules/
|   myLib/
|   |   dist/
|   |   |   subModule/
|   |   |   |   index.js
|   |   |   |   index.d.ts
|   |   |   index.js
|   |   |   index.d.ts
|   |   node_modules/
|   |   src/
|   |   tsconfig.json
|   |   package.json
```

Which implies that when I'm trying to reference my library using `import X from "myLib"` I have to tell the compiler that the sources are in the /dist forlder, not that the root of myLib.

I solved this by adding a "main": "./dist/index.js" in the package.json of myLib

The problem is when I try to import a path relative to myLib
Like `import Y from "myLib/subModule"`

This time it doesn't work.
Because instead of looking at  `node_modules/myLib/dist/subModule` tsc is looking at `node_modules/myLib/subModules/dist/`  which doesn't exist.

How can I make the compiler to look at the right path for subModules ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve this by using the [`"paths"` key in the `"compilerOptions"`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) in your `tsconfig.json`. Something like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "myLib/*": "node_modules/myLib/dist/*"
    }
  }
}
```

Sadly, this is something of a [standing issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8305) with how the TypeScript compiler resolves definition files when you have a `"types"` key in your `package.json`.

Comment: Thanks. But then while it works with a plain `tsc`, when I try to build the test project using webpack (awesome-typescript-loader) I get a `Can't resolve 'myLib/subModule`.

Comment: Found the solution to my second problem. `awesome-typescript-loader` requires to add a resolve plugin when using advanced path resolution. https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader#advanced-path-resolution-in-typescript-20